# Azure REST API PUT Header in Node.js for Copying Blob

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk, header, put

Running the below GET request node.js works:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const account = 'account'
const containerName = 'container'
const blobName = 'picture.jpeg'
const blobUrl = `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}`

const key = 'accesskey'
const strTime = (new Date()).toUTCString();
const strToSign = `GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${strTime}\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${account}/\ncomp:list`;

const secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
const hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
const auth = `SharedKey ${account}:`+hashInBase64; 

let getConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'x-ms-date': strTime,
        'x-ms-version': "2020-10-02",
    }
}

   
export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        fetch(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list`, getConfig)
        .then( results => {
            if(results.status==200) {console.log('api works')} else {console.log(results)}},
            res.end()
        )
    } 
}
```

I then want to copy a blob with access tier "Archive". Running the same code with the below changes for a PUT request doesn't work:

const blobUrl = `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}`

const strToSign = `PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${strTime}\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${account}/\n${containerName}/\n${blobName}`;

```
const putConfig = {
    method: 'PUT', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'x-ms-date': strTime,
        'x-ms-version': "2020-10-02",
        'x-ms-copy-source': blobUrl,
        'x-ms-requires-sync':'true',
    }
}
```

fetch(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}`, putConfig)

Can anyone tell me what I need to change to run the PUT request successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `x-ms-copy-source` and `x-ms-requires-sync` request headers in your 2nd `strToSign`.

Essentially you will need to include all headers starting with `x-ms` in your canonicalized headers string.

You will also need to ensure that these headers are sorted alphabetically.

So your `strToSign` would be something like:

```
const strToSign = PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-copy-source:${blobUrl}\nx-ms-date:${strTime}\nx-ms-requires-sync:true\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${account}/\n${containerName}/\n${blobName}
```

Where `blobUrl` is the URL for the source blob that you want to copy.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-headers-string.

On a side note, have you looked at [`Azure Blob SDK for JavaScript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob)?

Comment: Thanks for sending this through. I checked blobUrl and I did as you said. I still get: 403 Error. 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure..

Copy & pasted your strToSign

// Header
const putConfig = {
    method: 'PUT', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'x-ms-copy-source': blobUrl,
        'x-ms-date': strTime,
        'x-ms-requires-sync':'true',
        'x-ms-version': "2020-10-02"
    }
}

Comment: Regarding the SDK: I tried, but the SDK does not allow 'copy blob from url' operations on blobs with tier access status "Archive". And that is what I need. Otherwise, yes I was able to use the SDK to copy "Hot" or "Cool" access tier blobs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Required attributes in the headers of the putConfig.

So, I see, two required attributes missing at this moment.
`x-ms-lease-id:<ID>` and `Content-Length: 0`
For a page blob or an append blob, the `Content-Length` value of this header must be set to zero, as Put Blob is used only to initialize the blob.

```js
const putConfig = {
    method: 'PUT', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'x-ms-date': strTime,
        'x-ms-version': "2020-10-02",
        'x-ms-copy-source': blobUrl,
        'x-ms-requires-sync':'true',
        'x-ms-lease-id': <ID>,
        'Content-Length': 0,
    }
}
```

In the getConfig, You have used `x-ms-version` above of  `2012-02-12`. So In version 2012-02-12 and newer, the `x-ms-lease-id:<ID>` value must specify an active, infinite lease for a leased blob. A finite-duration lease ID fails with 412 (Precondition Failed).

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob

So, You need to update the getConfig like this:-

```js
let getConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'x-ms-date': strTime,
        'x-ms-version': "2020-10-02",
        'x-ms-lease-id': <ID>,
    }
}
```

Comment: The lease header is optional and my blob has no active lease. Its lease status is: "unlocked' and its lease state is 'available'

Comment: Here is a public repo with the code: https://github.com/andresreibel/stackoverflow

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/82932#issue-1035702094 MSFT documentation error

Comment: MSFT removed the 'copy from blob url' upon a prompt that it is not suitable for rehydration of blobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/archive-rehydrate-overview